# Thread safe class

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

The following class's method `public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object[] args)` is called by a third party dll. This dll may or may not be multi-threaded.

The dll also calls `public bool InvokeRequired { get; }` to check if it should call the `BeginInvoke` method. The third party dll does this every time it gets a socket message from a server.

If the `InvokeRequired` is false, instead of calling `BeginInvoke` the dll publishes an event of the message to any method that is subscribed.

I want to use the `MessageSynchronizer` class (*below*) in an ASP.NET application.
The class will be created with a new instance on every request.

I am fairly new to multithreading, and I would like to know if the way I have designed this class is both thread safe and efficient.

An instance would be created like so:

```
var synchronizer = new MessageSynchronizer((x) => Console.WriteLine(x), MessageSynchronizer.CallbackOptions.Handle | MessageSynchronizer.CallbackOptions.Async);
```

Then the synchronizer instance gets passed to the third parties dll's constructor.
Is the below class adequate?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class MessageSynchronizer : ISynchronizeInvoke
    {
        private readonly object[] _locks = null;
        private readonly bool _isLockFree = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// For manual handling of softdial messages.
        /// </summary>
        public Action<string> Callback { get { return Get(() => _callback, 0); } set { Set(x => _callback = x, value, 0); } }
        private Action<string> _callback = null;

        public CallbackOptions Options { get { return Get(() => _options, 1); } set { Set(x => _options = x, value, 1); } }
        private CallbackOptions _options = CallbackOptions.None;

        private T Get<T>(Func<T> field, int locker)
        {
            if (_isLockFree)
                throw new Exception("Cannot get properties as CallbackOptions is set to Never.");
            lock (_locks[locker])
                return field();
        }

        private void Set<T>(Action<T> field, T value, int locker)
        {
            if (_isLockFree)
                throw new Exception("Cannot set properties as CallbackOptions is set to Never.");
            lock (_locks[locker])
                field(value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use the default CampaignManagerClass's event
        /// subscriber pattern (recommended).
        /// </summary>
        public MessageSynchronizer(CallbackOptions options = CallbackOptions.None)
        {
            _callback = null;
            _options = options;
            _isLockFree = options.HasFlag(CallbackOptions.Never);

            if (!_isLockFree)
            {
                _locks = new object[]
                {
                    new object(),
                    new object()
                };
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use custom message reading, the CampaignManagerClass's event callbacks
        /// will be ignored and your custom message handler will be used instead
        /// (with the CallbackOptions.HandleCallback flag set).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="callback">A method that takes the raw softdial socket messages.</param>
        /// <param name="options">The callback options when messages are received.</param>
        public MessageSynchronizer(Action<string> callback, CallbackOptions options = CallbackOptions.None)
            :this()
        {
            if (callback == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");

            _callback = callback;
            _options = options;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The protected override MessageReceived(string) method
        /// from the RouterNet.RouterConnection (in RouterNet.dll) class calls this method
        /// when it gets a message from the Sytel.Mdn2.dll and this.InvokeRequired is true.
        /// The RouterConnection is a static field on the
        /// CampaignManager.CampaignManagerClass (in RouterNet.dll).
        /// </summary>
        public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
        {
            var message = (string)args[0];  // The args passed from CampaignManagerClass.RouterConnection.MessageReceived is always one, non-null string.
            var options = Options;

            /* *
             * The if statement below is designed in such a way as
             * to minimise lock contention. While deadloacks aren't possible,
             * locks are only taken when necessary, this can avoid
             * thread blocking. Locks are implemented in the properties.
             */

            if (options.HasFlag(CallbackOptions.Handle))
            {
                var callback = Callback;
                if (callback != null && message != string.Empty)  // The message should never be empty, but just incase.
                {
                    if (options.HasFlag(CallbackOptions.Async))
                    {
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            Callback(message);
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Callback(message);
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public object EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool InvokeRequired
        {
            get {  return _isLockFree ? false : Options.HasFlag(CallbackOptions.Handle); }
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum CallbackOptions
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The callback method will be ignored.
            /// </summary>
            None = 0,

            /// <summary>
            /// If provided, the callback method will
            /// be called with the message from softdial
            /// instead of default subscribed event.
            /// </summary>
            Handle = 1,

            /// <summary>
            /// If when calling the callback method
            /// the call should be done asynchronously,
            /// by default it's called synchronously.
            /// </summary>
            Async = 2,

            /// <summary>
            /// Any attempt to set the change the callback
            /// method or CallbackOptions results in an
            /// exception. This option avoid locks
            /// altogether, but still remaining thred safe.
            /// </summary>
            Never = 4
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure about the lock-objects array. Nice question, welcome to CR!

Comment: @retailcoder Yeh, I could have made two objects for the locks, but the array pattern appeals to me for some reason. I assume even through the locks are in an array they are still mutually exclusive, but I'm not 100% on that. Thanks for the welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you intend to be thread-safe. Right now just the access to the `Callback` and `Options` properties is locked and those locks are useless because [reference assignment in C# is guaranteed to be atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209623/is-a-reference-assignment-threadsafe).

If you assume that your locking will achieve that the call `Callback(message);` is mutually exclusive then you are mistaken.

So you can replace this code block:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// For manual handling of softdial messages.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<string> Callback { get { return Get(() => _callback, 0); } set { Set(x => _callback = x, value, 0); } }
    private Action<string> _callback = null;

    public CallbackOptions Options { get { return Get(() => _options, 1); } set { Set(x => _options = x, value, 1); } }
    private CallbackOptions _options = CallbackOptions.None;

    private T Get<T>(Func<T> field, int locker)
    {
        if (_isLockFree)
            throw new Exception("Cannot get properties as CallbackOptions is set to Never.");
        lock (_locks[locker])
            return field();
    }

    private void Set<T>(Action<T> field, T value, int locker)
    {
        if (_isLockFree)
            throw new Exception("Cannot set properties as CallbackOptions is set to Never.");
        lock (_locks[locker])
            field(value);
    }
```

with

```
    public Action<string> Callback { get; set; }
    public CallbackOptions Options { get; set; }
```

and it will behave the same as before.

If your goal is that in the case of two threads calling `BeginInvoke` at the same time the callbacks are executed mutually exclusive then you need to wrap the call in a lock:

```
 private readonly object _callbackLock = new object();

 ...

 lock (_callbackLock) { Callback(message); }
```

**Update**

In `BeginInvoke` you make a local copy `callback = Callback` but when invoking the action you use the property again rather than the copy - you should fix that.

Comment: Hey Chris, I don't want **Callback(message)** to be _mutually exclusive_, rather I want the settings (_Callback_ and _Options_) on the **MessageSynchronizer** object to take effect when new calls are made to the **BeginInvoke** Method. So what ever thread the **BeginInvoke** is called on never reads old values for **Callback** and **Options**. I want the result such that once you change the public properties, the next callback will use those new values no matter the state of interacting threads.

Comment: So are you saying I can remove all the locks and no matter what thread reads or writes to the properties, the reads will never be out of sync with the writes?

Comment: @user1909158: I'm not sure what you mean by "the reads will never be out of sync with the write", but as it stand yes you can remove the locks - they are not gaining you anything. In `BeginInvoke` you make a local copy `callback = Callback` but when invoking the action you use the property again rather than the copy - you should fix that.

Comment: Good catch on the callback, I didn't realize that. As for _the reads will never be out of sync with the write_ I'm referring to register caching of the reads, so a core might have *bool x = true* on cache, but another core updated *x = false*, and in main memory that's now the real value of *x*. Locking prevents this problem right? Atomic reads and writes mean a variable is always written to or read from in its complete state. i.e. A write isn't interrupted halfway through saving *string s = "stackexchange."*.

Comment: So you are worried about the fact that one thread updates the properties and another thread calls `BeginInvoke` but somehow has the references to the previous property values cached? I doubt that a thread will have these values in the cache across function calls. You could create two backing fields rather than auto-properties and make the backing field volatile - this will enforce a load.